# How to save only date part with mongoose, not in ISODate format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I save only date part with mongoose schmea. Currently my model is like this:

`myDate: { type: Date}`

Which saves date as `"2016-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"` even if I pass only:  "2016-02-27".

Comment: Why so prefer ```2016-02-27``` over ```2016-02-27T00:00:00.000Z``` ?

Comment: Well, I only need date, for example for a booking date, It can save me some place to convert it to only date format, if it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using:

```
dateOfBirth: { type: Object }
```

and saving like:

```
dateOfBirth: {year: 1988, month: 0, day: 8}
```

this gives me:

1. ability to search by `year`, `month`
2. ability to make date object:

   ```
   const dateOfBirth = new Date(
     user.dateOfBirth.year, 
     user.dateOfBirth.month, 
     user.dateOfBirth.day
   );
   ```

which will avoid timezone shiftings, since date object will be created on device's environment

---

**UPD**

P.S. I was not writing pros and cons since my answer was about alternative way of storing date separately and it should be obvious when this approach used.

After chatting with **[SergiiStotskyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445507/sergii-stotskyi)** in comments below I decided to put pros and cons to warn devs to choose best solution.

Keep in mind this approach has very few benefit(s).

Pros (I could find only two):

1. separate year, month, day fields helps to filter by exact year, month, day. Like: find all records for May month grouped by Year (to compare differences for months for previous years).
2. in comparison with Date which sensitive to timezone,  year, month, day is does not shift by timezone
3. **not exactly benefit**, date can be saved  as it comes from client-side if every element date was separate too

Cons:

1. If needed to get records by age it will be hard to determine, will require approximation used by year field (which in my use cases fits best, since no-one cares exact numbers in my project)
2. For exact age filtering will require aggregate with matching by year and reducing by filtering out of range items
3. Need to validate leap year

Comment: how would you filter people by age with this format? It becomes a nightmare  to deal with

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi in mongoose I’m already filtering it using year field. Also who said that there is requirement for age filtering? I know it’s not exact age filtering, but in my project nobody says that it should be exact. In any case it can be done using aggregate pipeline which mongodb provides. First step of aggregate will be matching by year, then reduce step will remove out of scope parts. And ad we use solid methodology in programming we can abstract aggreagation inside a self responsible method.

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi everything depends on use cases. Like who cares about numbers it that numbers are thousands? Means nobody rejected the idea of approximation.

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi my methodology helps with filtering by only year or year and month and etc. so it’s not dedicated for exact age filtering. But again it can be done using aggregate with 2 steps.

Comment: I think that solution adds more complexity. First, it's a subdoc which requires to have validation for month, days taking into consideration leap years. Second, it's become harder to search over this, requires custom logic or rely on approximation (as you said). Third, I feel pain rewriting such solution because previous developers did exactly what you suggested without any additional thought about consequences. 
Fourth, it requires compound index in order to search over date field.

So, maybe it makes sense to add consequences of such decision in your answer?

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi It’s not subdoc, it’s object. Yes it’s used for approximation. Bu again I don’t feel pain to write aggregate for age filtering in social network. Yes I do use indexes. Feel free to add to my answer and become coauthor, define pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

Behind the scene, a mongoose date is just like a `date` in javascript : it stores hours, seconds etc... There is no distinction with date/datetime like in SQL. In for a penny, in for a pound. That being said, it just a matter of display.

The reason is that mongo doesn't [support](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) this kind of type. You could create an object with year/month/day properties but it would be a pain to deal with.